# Increase Memory when using a Dynamic Array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, realloc

First of all I want to say that I did search around, but I didn't understand the solutions proposed to the existing questions.

Here is my question.

```
Array *create()
{
        static Array *arr1;
        void *arraypointer;

        if ((arraypointer = (Array *) malloc(sizeof(Array))) == NULL) {
                printf("Array not created because no memory is available. \n");
        } else {
                arraypointer = arr1;
                printf("Array created successfully. \n");
        }

        return arr1;
}
```

I am assuming that that is good. Now, I want to add something to the array, so obviously I need to increase the size in memory. At the moment, I have this.

```
void add(Array S[], Item x)
{
        static Array *arr1;
        void *arraypointer;

        arraypointer = (Array *) malloc(sizeof(Array) + 1);

        if (is_element_of(x, S) == true) {
                printf
                    ("Item already exists in array and therefore it can't be added. \n");
        } else {
                strcpy(S->arr1[S->s].sinput, x.sinput);
                S->arr1[S->s].iinput = x.iinput;
                S->s++;
                printf("Item added successfully. \n");
        }

}
```

I feel this is not good, although I am not sure how I have to do it. The warning I get is that arr1 and arraypointer are not used in the Add method.

What should I do?

Thanks

P.S. I would appreciate if you keep it simple, as I am still trying to wrap my head around this malloc thing.

Comment: Do something about the indentation

Comment: .. also why are you using `void *`

Comment: Please show us the `Array` structure.

Comment: The code of your `create` function confirms that you are quite confused. Why would the variable that holds the return value be `static`? Why is the temporary that holds the return of `malloc` of type `void*`? Why don't you initialize it directly at the declaration? Why do you cast the return of `malloc`? Why do you compare the value to `NULL`, instead of using the pointer value directly as a condition? Why do you assign that way in the `else` clause? You urgently need to read the faqs of SO and other sides.

Comment: I fixed your indentation.  Take a good look at what you're doing now, see if it isn't clearer.

Comment: To resize you use realloc, also if you want to throw an error in your `add` function because the element "already exists" you should do this check before you bother to allocate more memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is different from yours but It feel like the following

```
typedef int Item;

typedef struct da {
    size_t s;//now size of array
    Item *arr;//dynamic array
} Array;

Array *create(void){
    Array *ap;

    if((ap = malloc(sizeof(Array)))== NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Array not created because no memory is available. \n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Array created successfully. \n");
        ap->s = 0;
        ap->arr = NULL;
    }
    return ap;
}

bool is_equal(Item x, Item y){
    return x == y;
}

bool is_element_of(Item x, Array *S){
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < S->s ; ++i){
        if(is_equal(x, S->arr[i]))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void add(Array *S, Item x){
    if (is_element_of(x, S) == true){
        fprintf(stderr, "Item already exists in array and therefore it can't be added. \n");
    } else {
        S->arr = realloc(S->arr, (S->s + 1) * sizeof(Item));
        if(S->arr == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Memmory could not allocate.\n");
        } else {
            S->arr[S->s++] = x;
            fprintf(stderr, "Item added successfully. \n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @The__Malteser If you can not use `size_t` in your environment if
either use the `unsigned long`(or `unsigned long long`) instead of `size_t` or 
I think that it should do such as `typedef unsinged long size_t`.

Comment: `size_t` in `stddef.h`

Answer (score 0):

Once you allocated memory with `malloc` and resize it afterwards, you'll have to use `realloc`. Otherwise, if you use `malloc` again you'll get a whole new array. Furthermore, if you forget to call `free`, you'll get a memory leak, b/c the "old" array is not freed.  With `realloc` the content of your current array is preserved.

Also have a look at this related question: [Differences between using realloc vs. free -> malloc functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401234/differences-between-using-realloc-vs-free-malloc-functions)

Comment: That makes more sense now. So my real question now, is how can i use the realloc. I'll do a bit of research on how to use the realloc. I might come back for more help though.

Comment: It's not that hard. You give it the pointer and it's new size.  Usually the size is larger or smaller than the current size, so it doesn't take a difference or similar. `realloc` then returns the address where it allocated the memory and moved the arrays content.

Answer (score 0):

> I am assuming that that is good.

No, it's not, sorry. Look at your code carefully: assuming `malloc` is successfull, first, it assigns a newly allocated memory region to `arraypointer` (which doesn't really have a reason to be `void *`, you should make it `Array *`), and then it assigns `arr1` to `arraypointer`. After that, you just lost reference to the previously allocated block. Thus, your program contains a memory leak.

I don't see the point of using `arr1`, and I can't understand why you made it `static`. Why not something like this?

```
Array * create()
{
    Array *arraypointer;

    if ((arraypointer = malloc(sizeof(*arraypointer))) == NULL) {
        printf("Array not created because no memory is available. \n");
    }  else {
        printf("Array created successfully. \n");
    }
    return arraypointer;
}
```

The warning that you get inside `add()` is because you're not really using `arr1` nor `arraypointer`: you're just using `S`. Nowhere in the function's code you use these variables. I'm guessing you will want to use `realloc` here, but it is hard to tell, since you didn't show us the structure definition for `Array`.